# SMS MobileConnect Bounce Reason Code

Tags: mobileconnect, data-views, bounce-management

Is there a way to get the *reason* for an SMS bounce? I see that the "Undeliverable SMS" data view shows *if* a subscriber has bounced, but it doesn't show the reason for the bounce.

**I'd specifically like to know the following:**

- The subscriber's device is turned off
- The subscriber is out of range of the cellular network
- The number is a landline

**The final data extension would have at least these attributes:**

- MobileNumber
- SMS Bounce Reason (Code)

Answer (score 0):

For regular SMS sends and Journey SMS sends this isn't yet available as far as I know.

However, if you send SMS via MobileConnect API or the newer Transactional Send API, then you do get back a [**status code**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/sms-status-codes.html) which includes the possible reason of SMS bounce.